# Recognize click on configurable widget

Tags: android

I'm hosting widgets inside my app and need to know when user clicked on a widget, or when widget configuration intent started (for widget with configuration)

OnUserLeaveHint is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your widget with some layout and override the onInterceptTouchEvent method.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented exactly what you are trying to achieve. The idea of the solution is to set OnClick pending intent to the widget with bundle parameter of is_clicked=true.

This is what you can do:

**1.**
In the same place where you set your layout of the widget by using RemoteViews, do the next:

```
/*
 * Create pending intent to configuration activity
 */
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigurationMainActivity.class);

/*
 * Add values with this intent: widget id, and is_clicked = true
 */
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
extra.putBoolean(ConfigurationMainActivity.IS_ON_WIDGET_CLICK_KEY, true);
intent.putExtras(extra);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

/*
 * Set this intent to one of the views in the widget
 */
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_main, pendingIntent);
```

---

**2.**
When the user clicks on the widget, the `ConfigurationMainActivity` activity is opened.
In this activity do the next coding:

```
public static final String IS_ON_WIDGET_CLICK_KEY = "IS_ON_WIDGET_CLICK_KEY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // some usual stuff
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    // get the widget id that was transferred from on click event
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    // ---> here is what you asking for --->
    // check whereas the widget was clicked by the user or not
    boolean isOnWidgetClick = extras.getBoolean(IS_ON_WIDGET_CLICK_KEY, false);

    if (isOnWidgetClick)
    {
        // ----- Do here whatever you want ------
    }
    else 
    {
        // the code of first time widget configuration 
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

**Note:**:

- IS_ON_WIDGET_CLICK_KEY - is just a constant that is used in more than one class. You can see it in remote views setting and here

Hope, I could help you.

Comment: I solved it in a simpler way, just intercept the click with my widget container.